# Send e-mail with a link to another page

Tags: asp.net, email, hyperlink

I already know how to send either a plane text or html e-mail from an aspx page. My worry is how to create a link to another page within the same application in the e-mail body.

For instance, If a user clicks a Save button in page1.aspx, an e-mail should be sent to someone with a link to page2.aspx as part of the body of the e-mail.

Any help will be greately appreciated.

Comment: you can just pass the page name in mail's body like this `http://yourwebsiteurl.com/abc.aspx`

Comment: Please let me explain what I want to achieve. I have a gridview in page2.aspx that a manager needs to access in order to approve some request. I wants an e-mail sent to the manager from page1.aspx which is the page for creating the request. The e-mail should contain a link that the manager can click and it takes him/her to page2.aspx with the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to send html e-mail, why don't you put something like that in the body:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/url/page2.aspx">Link to page2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the body of the email you can add an anchor tag. The href attribute of the anchor tag will point to the URL where you want to redirect the user. The inner text will be the text which the user sees. If you want the link to open the target in another tab, use the target attribute, like this:

```
Lick <a href="http://i.dont.know.com" target="_blank">here</a> to continue...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am confused, the application is still at the development stage so I am accessing it through localhost and when I finally publish the application it is going to be having a different url. Is there no way I can specify a url that can in the href tag without having to change it when I am publishing the application?

Comment: Of course there is a way. You can use a server tag where you want your link and the server tag (containing your anchor) will be generated server-side.

Comment: please pardon my ignorance, I am a beginner programmer. Page2.aspx will be accessed from an e-mail client but within the same network as the server hosting the application. I dont know how to use the anchor in a server tag and what url to use so that I would not have to change it when I finally host the application. Please show me how to do this.

Comment: You can add a server tag in the markup. In visual basic a server tag looks like this: <%=foo%>. In code behind you can define the foo property to hold a string which contains your anchor.